# For $g(x) = 1/x$ extended to complex-values, what is antiderivative of $g$?

Tags: complex-analysis, lebesgue-integral, complex-integration, dirac-delta

My question is similar to the questions

> For $g(x) = 1/x$, determine the antiderivative, and determine  its definite integral.

Except I want to use complex-valued variables and functions.

---

First, I hypothesize the most parsimonious auxilary function possible that might work. My intuition says to use overlay a Dirac delta distribution on top  of the reciprocal function. Maybe the following?

By $A \subset \mathbb{C}$, I denote a set defined by $\left\{x + i 0  \in \mathbb{C} \mid  x \leq 0  \right\}$. By $g : ? \to ?$ I denote an auxiliary function that I define as
$$g(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
i\delta_{x+iy}(A)
&~\text{for}~ x+iy \in A; \text{and}
\\
\frac{1}{x+iy}
&~\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Questions:

(1) Does $g(x,y)$ have an antiderivative?

(2) What is its antiderivative?

(3) Is the definite integral zero around any closed path?

In the pticture below, I give a closed path. The path integral should equal zero taken along the path.

[image]

Comment: as written $1/(x-iy)$ your function is not holomorphic so it doesn't have a holomorphic antiderivative; if it were $1/(x+iy)=1/z$ as in the title, then an antiderivative exists locally being an (arbitrary) local branch of $\log z$ but it doesn't exist on the full punctured plane

Comment: There are quite a few issues (I haven't fully read it), but one big one is that your function $f$ isn't well defined on all of $U$. In writing $\arctan(y/x)$, you're assuming that $x \neq 0$. But clearly there are points in $U$ of the form $(0,y)$, where $y \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. Since the function isn't even properly defined, it can't be a primitive of $g$. Currently, your question is "what is an anti-derivative/primitive of $g$". The answer is that $g$ has no primitive. It is only if you restrict the domain of $g$ to be a simply-connected subset of $U$ that it has a primitive.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Branch_cuts

Comment: $\log$ function lives here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Riemann_surface_log.svg not $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Antiderivative of $1/z$ is ''multi valued'' function, which is not a function. (Think of $\exp(0) = \exp(2\pi i)$.) To avoid this situation we need to introduce the notion of branch cut. Or, one can think of more natural domain (say, Riemann surface of $\log)$ that our function is not multi-valued.

Comment: All this is clarified in Complex Analysis Stein-Shakarachi Chapter 1 and 3. I recommend that you read those chapters. In fact this is the starting point of Algebraic Topology in Complex Analysis, you will need to have a simply connected Domain to define $\log(z)$ unambiguously. So on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$, one cannot have a $\log$ function well defined there.

Comment: Please avoid too frequent edits.

Answer (score 5):

DISCLAIMER: Since OP edited his original question, changing it **completely**, the following post doesn’t seem to answer the question anymore.

---

A complex function $g:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ ($\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ open) has an antiderivative iff $\oint_\gamma g(z)\ \text{d} z = 0$ for any closed path $\gamma$ contained in $\Omega$. Your $g$ does not satisfy this assumption in $\Omega = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0\}$, therefore it fails to have an antiderivative.

On the other hand, your $g$ possesses a multi-valued antiderivative, namely $G(z) = \log z = \ln |z| + \imath\ \operatorname{arg} z$ (here $\ln$ stands for the *real* natural logarithm): in fact, each single-valued branch $\phi$ of $G$ is holomorphic and satisfies $\phi^\prime (z) = \frac{1}{z} = g(z)$ for each $z$ in its domain.

Comment: $\operatorname{arg} z$ is the *argument* (or *phase*) *of $z\neq 0$*, i.e. any angle $\theta$ s.t. $z=|z| e^{\imath \theta}$. Each $z\neq 0$ has countable many arguments, only one of which lies on the interval $]-\pi, \pi]$: this particular value is called *principal argument of $z$* and it is denoted with $\operatorname{Arg} z$. All the other arguments of $z$ differ from $\operatorname{Arg} z$ by an integer multiple of $2\pi$, i.e. $\operatorname{arg} z = \operatorname{Arg} z + 2 k \pi$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: In order to choose a single-valued branch of $G(z) = \log z$ you have to: **1**. choose any connected open subset $U \subset \mathbf{C} \setminus \{0\}$ which doesn't contain any closed path *homotopic to the point $0$*, i.e. any open subset $U$ s.t. any closed path $\gamma \subset U$ does not wrap around $0$; and **2**. choose $\operatorname{arg} z$ for $z \in U$ in such a way that $\ln |z| + \imath \operatorname{arg} z$ is continuous and holomorphic in $U$. Then $U$ is the domain of the branch.

Comment: For example, the *principal branch* of $\log z$ is defined in $U = \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ (the complex plane minus the nonpositive real axis) by taking $\operatorname{arg} z = \operatorname{Arg} z$ for each $z \in U$.

Comment: Your solution, i.e. $G(z) = \operatorname{Log} z$, fails to be continuous on the negative real axis, therefore it is not complex-differentiable at any point $z_0 = x_0 + 0\cdot \imath$ with $x_0 <0$. Hence your $G$ isn’t an antiderivative of $g(z) = 1/z$ in the whole of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ 0\}$.

Comment: May I give you a tip? Complex Analysis is better studied from textbooks than from WIKIpedia. There are many good books on the topic, e.g. Greene & Krantz’s *Function Theory of One Complex Variable* (which is relatively new and simple) or Ahlfors’ *Complex Analysis* (which, on the other hand, is classical). Try study from one of these. ;-)